# my collision 2d doesn't work in C# on Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm learning C# while programming my game, I'm stuck doing the movement. I want my character to move continuously by pressing 'D' or 'A' once. Then, after colliding with an invisible wall while going to the right, go backwards until it hits another invisible wall and stop. 
I managed to make my `GameObject` move, but when it collides with the wall, nothing happens. Both objects have a `rigidbody2D`, the same z-coordinates, and correct tags.

```
public class SquadMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    float speed;
    bool collisionRightWall = false;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.D)) {  

            CancelInvoke ();
            InvokeRepeating ("RightMovement", Time.deltaTime, Time.deltaTime);

        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.A)) {

            CancelInvoke ();
            InvokeRepeating ("LeftMovement", Time.deltaTime, Time.deltaTime);

        }
    }

    void RightMovement () {

        speed = 10f;
        transform.Translate (speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);

    }

    void LeftMovement () {

        speed = -7f;
        transform.Translate (speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);

    }

    void OnCollisionWallR (Collider2D colR) {

        if (colR.gameObject.tag == "invisibleWallRight") {

            collisionRightWall = true;
            Debug.Log (collisionRightWall);

        }
    }
}
```

I'm using invisible walls because I don't know how to use x-coordinates, There HAS to be a more efficient way but I want to know first why this don't work. I would be glad if someone could teach me that too.

Comment: Where is the logic that sends the player back after collider triggers?

Comment: what is the CancelInvoke ();
InvokeRepeating ("LeftMovement", Time.deltaTime, Time.deltaTime); ? The Update method gets called every frame automatically, you don't need to use InvokeRepeating. And to answer your question, as gjttt1 said, just changed the OnCollisionWallR (Collider2D colR) to OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D colR)

Comment: He's checking for input every frame but it isn't called every frame. InvokeRepeating is only called on the frame that the Key is pressed down.

Answer (score 0):

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SquadMovement : MonoBehaviour {

```
float constantspeed = 3;
float speed;

//Key inputs

void Update () {

    transform.Translate (constantspeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.D)) {  

        StopAllCoroutines ();
        StartCoroutine (RightMovement(0f));
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.A)) {

        StopAllCoroutines ();
        StartCoroutine (LeftMovement(0f));
    }
}

//Movement itself (Right, Left)

IEnumerator RightMovement (float Rloop) {

    while (transform.position.x < Time.time * constantspeed + 6) {

        speed = 10f;
        transform.Translate (speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (Rloop);
    }

    if (transform.position.x > Time.time * constantspeed + 5.9) {

        StopAllCoroutines ();
        StartCoroutine (LeftMovement (0f));
    }
}

IEnumerator LeftMovement (float Lloop) {

    while (transform.position.x > Time.time * constantspeed -8) {

        speed = -7f;
        transform.Translate (speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (Lloop);
    }
}
```

}