# Unity: Detect if player is in an area

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello I'm making a 2d game on unity and I m having areas in my game where the action is different like if player enters the zone only then he's supposed to shoot

Sorry for the bad quality of the image in on my phone and tried to draw something as an example the red circle is the player and the blue rectangles is the area I'm supposed to detect

[image: example]

Comment: What have you done so far? if nothing, [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html) can be a good start

Comment: I've used a panel added it 2d box collider but it changes players position is it possible to make a 2d box collider and make the player pass trough it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that's actually pretty easy.
You just have to use invisible panels with a trigger event if the player walks through

Comment: I've used a panel added it 2d box collider but it changes players position is it possible to make a 2d box collider and make the player pass trough it?

Comment: Yes: [Collider.isTrigger](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-isTrigger.html)

Comment: Seems like Senbazuru was faster hehe.
Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816388/my-collision-2d-doesnt-work-in-c-sharp-on-unity) could help you?

Comment: Great! Thanks guys I've red the docs :) I'll try it out tonight :)

Comment: Ur welcome and ty for the up-vote :)
If u need any help just scream, eh i mean comment again :P

Comment: okay well I was using `private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)`, But I had to use `private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)` so i could get the collision